# How come the refresh method is called twice and called when cancel button is hitted?

Tags: java, swing

Does anyone know why btnAdd.addActionListener() is called twice, whenever i need it only once, say dialog is returned from TradeOutDialog, refresh() is called twice, sometimes I hit Cancel from the TradeOutDialog, btnAdd.addActionListener() is called upon as well.
Don't know why. I expect it to happen once.
Thanks

```
public class TradeOut extends JPanel {

    private JTable tblTradeOut = new JTable();
    private JPanel residualPanel = new JPanel();
    private JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
    private JPanel p = new JPanel();
    private JPanel btnPanel = new JPanel();
    private JButton btnAdd = new JButton("新增");
    //private JTextField residual;
    private FormattedCurrencyTextField residual;
    private BigDecimal residualValue;
    private TradeIn ti;
    private JLabel lblTotal = new JLabel("差价");


    private TradeOutDialog dialog;
    private List<TradeOutProduct> ltop = new ArrayList<>();
    private Database db;
    private BigDecimal total ;


    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel() {
            String[] ColNames = new String[] {
                //"追加品类","大类名称","数量","","追加价","销售员"

                  "SKU",  "品类", "数量", "售价", "重量", "单位价", "总追加价"
            };

             @Override
             public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
                 if (columnIndex == 3 || columnIndex == 4)
                     return java.lang.Integer.class;
                  return super.getColumnClass(columnIndex); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
             }



            @Override
            public int getColumnCount() {
                return ColNames.length;
            }

            @Override
            public String getColumnName(int column) {
                return ColNames[column]; //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
            }



        };



    public TradeOut(Database _db, TradeIn _ti, BigDecimal value) throws SQLException, ParseException
    {
         this.db = _db;
         this.ti = _ti;


         this.setLayout(new MigLayout("insets 0 0 0 0"));



        mainPanel.setLayout(new MigLayout("insets 0 0 0 0"));

        btnPanel.setLayout(new MigLayout("insets 0 0 0 0"));

        btnPanel.add(btnAdd);

        residualPanel.setLayout(new MigLayout("insets 0 0 0 0"));
         MaskFormatter mask = new MaskFormatter("¥###########.##");
         residual = new FormattedCurrencyTextField(mask);
         total = new BigDecimal(0);

        residual.setText(String.valueOf(value));

        residualValue = value;
        residualPanel.add(lblTotal);
        residualPanel.add(residual, "width 20%");

        residual.setEditable(false);

        dialog = new TradeOutDialog(db, ti);

        btnAdd.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                addTradeOutBtnActionPerformed(evt);
            }

            private void addTradeOutBtnActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                if (evt.getSource() == btnAdd) {
                 dialog.setVisible(true);
                  refresh();
                }



            }
        });

        dialog.getAdd().addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
             try {
                 addItemBtnActionPerformed(evt);
             } catch (SQLException ex) {
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "系统错误信息，请联络技术支援");
                 Logger.getLogger(TradeOut.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
             }
            }

            private void addItemBtnActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) throws SQLException {
                TradeOutProduct top = new TradeOutProduct();
                top.setProductID(String.valueOf(String.valueOf(dialog.getCategory()) + String.valueOf(dialog.getSubCategory()) + dialog.getProduct().trim()));
                top.setSKUName(dialog.getSKUName().trim());
                top.setCategoryID(dialog.getCategory());
                top.setSubCategoryID(dialog.getSubCategory());
                top.setQuantity(dialog.getTxtQuantity().intValue());
                top.setWeight(dialog.getTxtWeight());
                top.setUnitPrice(dialog.getTxtUnitPrice());
                top.setTradeOutPrice(dialog.getTxtTradeOutPrice());
                //top.setEmpID(dialog.getCbEmployeeID());




                ltop.add(top);
                dialog.setVisible(false);

            }
        });




        p.setLayout(new MigLayout("insets 0 0 0 0"));


        tblTradeOut.setModel(model);
        tblTradeOut.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);

        TableColumnModel m = tblTradeOut.getColumnModel();
         m.getColumn(3).setCellRenderer(NumberRenderer.getCurrencyRenderer());

        m.getColumn(5).setCellRenderer(NumberRenderer.getCurrencyRenderer());
        m.getColumn(6).setCellRenderer(NumberRenderer.getCurrencyRenderer());


        mainPanel.add(btnPanel, "height 10%, width 100%, wrap");
        mainPanel.add(new JScrollPane(tblTradeOut), "height 80%, width 100%, wrap");
        mainPanel.add(residualPanel, "height 10%, width 100%");


        this.add(mainPanel, "height 100%, width 100%");

    }


   public void refresh()
    {
        removeAllRows();
        int x = 0;
        BigDecimal atotal = BigDecimal.ZERO;


        for (TradeOutProduct top : ltop)
        {


               BigDecimal TradeOutPrice = top.getTradeOutPrice();
               int Quantity = top.getQuantity();

               int Weight = top.getWeight();
               BigDecimal UnitPrice = top.getUnitPrice();





               // for non-golden products
               if (Weight == 0 && UnitPrice.equals(BigDecimal.ZERO))
               {
                   top.setTotal(TradeOutPrice.multiply(new BigDecimal(Quantity)));
               }
               else if (Quantity == 0 && TradeOutPrice.equals(BigDecimal.ZERO))
               {
                    top.setTotal(UnitPrice.multiply(new BigDecimal(Weight) ));
               }
               model.addRow(new Object[]{ 
                   top.getProductID(),top.getSKUName(),Quantity, TradeOutPrice, Weight, UnitPrice, top.getTotal() });
             /*((DefaultTableModel) tblTradeIn.getModel()).addRow(new java.util.Vector<String>(java.util.Arrays.asList(new String[]{getDate(), getTime(),tip.getProductID(),tip.getCategoryID(),String.valueOf(tip.getQuantity()),tip.getTradeInPrice(),tip.getTradeInPrice()*tip.getQuantity() })));  */
             total = atotal.add(top.getTotal());
             residualValue = residualValue.subtract(top.getTotal());

        // the customer still has value to remain, retailer  always want to sell product
        if (residualValue.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) >= 0){
            residual.setText(String.valueOf(residualValue));
        }

        else
        {
            // the customer tradein price is too high, not acceptable
                //residual.setText("須要補價 - " + String.valueOf(Math.abs(residualValue)));
            residual.setMoney(residualValue.abs());
         }
        }


    }


    private void removeAllRows()
    {
        int rows = tblTradeOut.getRowCount();
         for (int i = rows-1; i >= 0; i--) {
                ((DefaultTableModel)tblTradeOut.getModel()).removeRow(i);
                         tblTradeOut.revalidate();
         }
    }

    public BigDecimal getTotal()
    {
        return total;
    }

    public JTextField getTotalTf()
    {
        return residual;
    }

    public String getProduct(int row)
    {
        return tblTradeOut.getValueAt(row, 0).toString();
    }

    public int getQuantity(int row)
    {
        return Integer.parseInt(tblTradeOut.getValueAt(row,2).toString());
    }

    public int getTradeOutPrice(int row)
    {
        return Integer.parseInt(tblTradeOut.getValueAt(row, 4).toString());
    }

    public String getEmp(int row)
    {
        return tblTradeOut.getValueAt(row, 5).toString();
    }


    public JTable getTable()
    {
        return tblTradeOut;
    }

}
```

Comment: You seem to be adding 2 actionlisteners to the btnAdd. One on the line that goes btnAdd.addActionListener() and one on the line that goes dialog.getAdd().addActionLister().

Comment: again similair question, please how we can test this code, not possible to run, isn't it, for better help sooner post an SSCCE, short runnable,  compilable, only with JFrame with JButton firing an event twice

Comment: Yes, Vincent. I know now